# gitignore wierdness: check-ignore shows file is ignored, but file shows as modified

Tags: git, gitignore

git status shows this:

```
# On branch master
# Changes not staged for commit:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
#   (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
#
#       modified:   InstructorsMvc/InstructorsMvc.Publish.xml
#       modified:   QiActivationMvc/QiActivationMvc.Publish.xml
#       modified:   QiMvc/QiMvc.Publish.xml
#
```

but I'm like... uh wait... my Publish.xml files (used by VS Ftp Deploy) are supposed to be ignored!

So I type `git check-ignore InstructorsMvc/InstructorsMvc.Publish.xml --verbose`:

```
.gitignore:118:*.[Pp]ublish.xml ".\\InstructorsMvc\\InstructorsMvc.Publish.xml"
```

So the file is correctly ignored in gitignore on line 118, but shows modified?

Um... what am I doing wrong here...?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like that file is in your git tree somewhere. So at some point you managed to add & commit it. `git rm <file>` will remove it as part of a new commit.

Comment: I believe I did that once already, and somehow they worked their way back in... :-/